# How do I prevent this dropdown from closing when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2mtm8wo5/

Since I need to use this on a single page layout, I need to stop the dropdown from closing when a link is clicked

### Javascript

```
//when I click dropdown menu
$('.sbr-dropdown').click(function(){
    //find list items
    $(this).find("ul").each(function(){
        //if dropdown is hidden, show it
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        }
        else //if dropdown is visible, hide it
        {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        }

    });
});
```

### HTML

```
   <div id="sbr">
        <div class="sbr-logo">Drop</div>
        <ul class="sbr-menu">
            <li class="sbr-item sbr-dropdown">Unsere Websites
                <ul class="sbr-submenu">
                    <li><a href="#seite1">Hansestadt Stralsund</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#seite2">Andere Alternative</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#seite3">Noch eine Seite</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sbr-item">Hansestadt</li>
            <li class="sbr-item sbr-dropdown">Einstellungen
                <ul class="sbr-submenu">
                    <li><a href="#seite1">Hansestadt Stralsund</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#seite2">Andere Alternative</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#seite3">Noch eine Seite</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The dropdown needs to be close only when the dropdown class is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop event propagation to child elements using:

```
$('.sbr-dropdown ul').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/06g44n34/)**

Answer (score 3):

To stop the fadeOut on click, you just need to remove the `else` condition:

```
$('.sbr-dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mtm8wo5/2/)

Alternatively, you can `stopPropagation` of the click event of the `a` elements themselves:

```
$('.sbr-menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mtm8wo5/4/)